# How to paste ith element of vector to ith element of list of vector

Tags: r, list, vector, paste

I have a vector of nth element and a list with the same number of elements, each is a vector. For a simple equivalent example:

```
v <- c("a","b")
num1 <- c(1,2,3)
num2 <- c(10,20,30)
numList <- list(num1,num2)
```

The output I want is:

```
"a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

I can do this with a for loop:

```
output <- vector() 
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
  output <- c(output, paste0(v[i], numList[[i]]))
}
output

[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

But is there an easier or more clever way, using `lapply` or `tidyverse`? I tried the following and did not get what I want:

```
lapply(numList, function(x) paste0(v, x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` instead of `lapply`

```
unname(unlist(Map(paste0, v, numList)))
```

-output

```
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

---

Or `stack` a named `list` into a two column data.frame and apply the `paste` once

```
with(stack(setNames(numList, v)), paste0(ind, values))
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

---

Or a faster version would be to `rep`licate the 'v' based on the `lengths` of the `list`, `unlist` the `list` and `paste`

```
paste0(rep(v, lengths(numList)), unlist(numList))
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

---

Or using `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map2(v, numList, str_c) %>%
    flatten_chr
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

Comment: Great! That's what I'm looking for. Much simpler! And thanks for the different approaches too.

Answer (score 2):

We can try the base R code below

```
> c(sapply(seq_along(v), function(k) paste0(v[k], numList[[k]])))
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "b10" "b20" "b30"
```

Comment: Good idea to use the `seq_along` to generate the index.  Apparently the `Map` from @akrun is also from base R, but I didn't know about it.